# How to test any iOS app with Appium

Tags: ios, iphone, appium

I need to test an app that I get from the app store, using Appium to create and drive the tests.  However, I can't find any instructions on accessing these apps from Appium.

This app is from the app store, its on my iPhone, but I don't know now to access the .app file from my mac or from the iOS simulator.

How would I go about this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Appium automation supports only for the iOS app which is in debug mode or signed with developer certificate.

And we can't do automation for app store .ipa/app since it is signed build and it is in release mode.

.app file is provided by developer.

Answer (score 1):

1.you must have .app file of ios app on mac system which you want to automate.
2. .app file is provided by developer.
3.you must have app installed on device(if u testing on real device).